# Is there a way in Dart to reuse method implementation in multiple Enums?

Tags: dart, enums, code-reuse, implements

I want to create 2 Enums (or even more later on) with a same field, and a same method relating to it, like:

```
enum Enum1 {
  A1('A1', 1),
  B1('B1', 2);

  String name;
  int x1;
  Enum1(this.name, this.x1);

  String concat(String s) {
    return name + s;
  }
}

enum Enum2 {
  A2('A2', 3),
  B2('B2', 4);

  String name;
  int x2;
  Enum2(this.name, this.x2);

  String concat(String s) {
    return name + s;
  }
}
```

What should I do to reuse the code of identical methods in different Enums?

Namely, how can I reuse the codes related to `name` and `concat` in the previous example?

I have tried to use a class to do implementation for both Enums, but it kept prompting me that I have to re-implement the `concat` method and the getter of `name` respectively in each Enum.

My failed attempt is like:

```
class Reuse {
  String name;
  String concat(String s) {
    return name + s;
  }
}

enum Enum1 implements Reuse {
  A1('A1',1), B1('B1',2);

  int x1;
  String name;
  Enum1(this.name, this.x1);

  String concat(String s);
}

enum Enum2 implements Reuse {
  A2('A2',3), B2('B2',4);

  int x2;
  String name;
  Enum2(this.name, this.x2);

  String concat(String s);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by declaring `Reuse` as a [mixin](https://dart.dev/language/mixins), and declaring the enums as `with Reuse` rather than `implements Reuse`.

The `implements` keyword does not inherit the implementation of methods  while `extends` and `with` do give you the implementation of the methods. And since enums in dart are restricted from using `extends`, this leaves `with` as the only option, and you can only use `with` with mixins.

```dart
mixin Reuse {
  String get name;
  String concat(String s) {
    return name + s;
  }
}

enum Enum1 with Reuse {
  A1('A1', 1),
  B1('B1', 2);

  final int x1;
  final String name;
  const Enum1(this.name, this.x1);
}

enum Enum2 with Reuse {
  A2('A2', 3),
  B2('B2', 4);

  final int x2;
  final String name;
  const Enum2(this.name, this.x2);
}

void main() {
  print(Enum1.A1.concat('example'));
  print(Enum2.A2.concat('example'));
}
```